# Require simple products in WooCommerce cart for product variations before checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

After adding some product variations to the cart, some simple products are required to match the product variations in cart.

If there are no correct simple products in cart, a message will display and user cannot proceed to checkout.

If product variations in cart, and required simple products are not in cart, then the notice should display.

```php
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart', 'product_cart_check');

function product_cart_check() {
    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item) {
        // Target product variation
        $product_variation_ids = array(27741);
        // Simple products should match the product variation
        $simple_product_ids = array(26924, 26925);

        if (in_array($cart_item['variation_id'], $product_variation_ids)) {
            if (!in_array($cart_item['product_id'], $simple_product_ids)) {
            // Display message
            wc_print_notice('Please add required simple products to your cart', 'notice');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have the code above, but it doesn't work as expected. The notice will always display even though I added required simple products to cart. Any advice?

Comment: It's really a good answer, sorry for accepting it so late. It seems my theme overrides the proceed to checkout action, now I use javascript to prevent the button from jumping to the checkout page. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To require simple products in cart for (a) product variation(s):

- Use the `woocommerce_check_cart_items` hook instead
- Use [array_diff()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to compares array against one or more other arrays and returns the values in array that are not present in any of the other arrays.
- To remove the proceed to checkout button, you can use the `woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout` hook

So you get, for a specific variation ID:

```php
function get_cart_item_ids() {
    // Initialize
    $ids = array();

    // WC Cart NOT null
    if ( ! is_null( WC()->cart ) ) {
        // Loop through cart contents
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents() as $cart_item ) {
            // Push to array
            $ids[] = $cart_item['data']->get_id();
        }
    }
    
    return $ids;
}

function action_woocommerce_check_cart_items() {
    // Get cart item ids
    $cart_item_ids = get_cart_item_ids();
    
    // Target product variation
    $product_variation_id = 27741;
    
    // Simple products should match the product variation
    $simple_product_ids = array( 26924, 26925 );
    
    // Checks if a value exists in an array
    if ( in_array( $product_variation_id, $cart_item_ids ) ) {
        // Computes the difference of arrays
        if ( array_diff( $simple_product_ids, $cart_item_ids ) ) {
            // Notice
            wc_print_notice( __( 'Please add required simple products to your cart', 'woocommerce' ), 'notice' ); 
            
            // Remove proceed to checkout button
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );
        }
    }
}   
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items' , 'action_woocommerce_check_cart_items', 10, 0 );
```

**OR** to apply the same for multiple product variation IDs:

```php
function get_cart_item_ids() {
    // Initialize
    $ids = array();

    // WC Cart NOT null
    if ( ! is_null( WC()->cart ) ) {
        // Loop through cart contents
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents() as $cart_item ) {
            // Push to array
            $ids[] = $cart_item['data']->get_id();
        }
    }
    
    return $ids;
}

function action_woocommerce_check_cart_items() {
    // Get cart item ids
    $cart_item_ids = get_cart_item_ids();
    
    // Target product variations
    $product_variation_ids = array( 27741, 56 );
    
    // Simple products should match the product variation
    $simple_product_ids = array( 26924, 26925 );
    
    // Initialize
    $flag = false;
    
    // Loop through
    foreach ( $product_variation_ids as $product_variation_id ) {   
        // Checks if a value exists in an array
        if ( in_array( $product_variation_id, $cart_item_ids ) ) {
            // Computes the difference of arrays
            if ( array_diff( $simple_product_ids, $cart_item_ids ) ) {
                $flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    // True
    if ( $flag ) {
        // Notice
        wc_print_notice( __( 'Please add required simple products to your cart', 'woocommerce' ), 'notice' ); 

        // Remove proceed to checkout button
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );   
    }   
}   
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items' , 'action_woocommerce_check_cart_items', 10, 0 );
```